# PaperClip uploaded file gives "can't dump file" when added to session

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I need the uploaded PaperClip file in multi step form. I passed the same in session, but it gives me "**can't dump file**".

I have following method in my controller:

```
def find_shared_ids
  session[:attachment] = params[:participant_attachments][:attachment]  
  @file_title = params[:participant_attachments][:file_title]
  @attachment = ParticipantAttachment.new(activity_params)
end
```

Following is my model:

```
class ParticipantAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :participant
  has_many :shared_attachments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :participants, through: :shared_attachments
  validates_presence_of :attachment

  has_attached_file :attachment, Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge(Settings.participant_attachments.paperclip)

  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, content_type: ['image/jpeg']
end
```

I get the follwing on my browser:

**Can't dump file**

**Parameters:**

> {"utf8"=>"✓", 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"d4Ck467KQqL0GOj2Y5hwrDxMI1Dcdbu6TulzmmuFPOg=", 
>   "participant_attachments"=>{"attachment"=>#, 
>   @original_filename="1505352_796594563718005_3237802925919628295_n.jpg",
>   @content_type="image/jpeg",  @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"participant_attachments[attachment]\";
>   filename=\"1505352_796594563718005_3237802925919628295_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type:
>   image/jpeg\r\n">,  "file_title"=>"refesf"},  "participant_ids"=>""}

I tried passing the same in hidden_field_tag in my view file. It takes the uploaded file as string and does not help.

Kindly help! :)

Comment: can you post what your form looks like, I thing that you need to add ` :html => { :multipart => true }` to your `form_for` but I cant be sure for sure